# How to read/get the CSS background color of a row in a gridview

Tags: jquery, css, colors, find, rows

I have set the background-color of a row via CSS

```
$("#gv tr:has(td)").each(function () {
                $(this).css({ "background-color": "green" });
})
```

After this , certain rows have been added

How can I loop through the rows and only again find the "green" rows?

```
$("#gv tr:has(td)").each(function () {
             ? (if row == green){
               }
})
```

Comment: FYI There's no need to do an each function to set them, just do: `$("#gv tr:has(td)").css({ "background-color": "green" });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use css() to get value of `background-color`

```
$("#gv tr:has(td)").each(function () {
     if($(this).css("background-color") == "green")
     {
     }
});
```

You can also use the DOM object to get color

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/883b6/)**

```
$("#gv tr:has(td)").each(function () {
     if(this.style.backgroundColor == "green")
     {
     }
});
```

Comment: returns e.g. rgb(222, 223, 222) but I can work with this ,thanks!

Comment: Check my updated answer to get background color value in plain format

Answer (score 3):

What if you decide to change the background-color from green?

**As an alternative solution**, if your application allows it, I would recommend simply adding a class to each row element that you wish to select later.  This would be much more maintainable and self documenting than identifying an element by a background color. e.g.

```
<td class="main-class green></td>
```

If you added a class to the appropriate elements, then you could easily select all of your *green* elements by the their selector.

Comment: Yes, add or remove class instead of change the style inline.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($(this).css("background-color") === "green")
```

Answer (score 0):

If($(this).css("background-color") == "green") { ... }